# d3 chaining append("x").attr("...").append("y".attr("...") inconsistency

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Why does this work

```
var defs = svg.append("defs")
    .append("marker")
    .attr({
        "id": "markerArrow",
        "markerWidth": 10,
        "markerHeight": 10,
        "orient": "auto"        
    })
    .append("path")
    .attr({
        "d": "M10,10 L20,20"
    })
```

but this not work

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .classed("node", true)
    .call(force.drag)
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", 10)
```

and only work when written as

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .classed("node", true)
    .call(force.drag)

node
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", 10)
```

Surely the node preceding .append("circle") in the last bit of code is just a placeholder reference to the lines of code above it? So how is it different in functionality?

Comment: as the second your appending the circle to the whole node, the first one your appending it to the 'g' inside the node

Comment: Your 2nd and 3rd code snippets are functionally equivalent. To the output they do exactly the same thing. The difference is that in the 2nd example `node` will afterwards hold a reference to the selection containing all appended `circle`s whereas in the 3rd snippet `node` will hold a reference to all appended `g`s. I'd guess we are not yet seeing the entire picture and your code is not going to break on these statements but on the difference of `node` later on. Please provide more details on your code and what exactly *does not work*.

Comment: You're correct. I had some additional code later on that used node.selectAll("circle").attr(....) which works when I use the 2nd code snippet but not when I use the 3rd presumably because the reference to node in the 3rd snippet is the circles themselves.

thanks for your help